# Specifying an affine linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> V is a vector space of dimension $n$ over field $\mathbb K$ and T:V$\rightarrow$V is an affine linear map. Is T completely specified if we specify T on $n+1$ points $v_1,v_2,...,v_{n+1}\in V$ such that $\{v_2-v_1,v_3-v_2,...,v_{n+1}-v_1\}$ spans V.

Is that true? The definition of affine linear maps we are taking is that

T:V$\rightarrow$V is said to be affine linear if $$\forall n\in \mathbb N,\forall \lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n\in\mathbb K\ \ such \ \ that \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=1,\forall v_1,v_2,...,v_n\in V,$$
$$T\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iv_i\Bigg)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iT(v_i)$$

**My progress**

Take a vector $v\in V$, then $v=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i(v_{i+1}-v_1)$
$$\Rightarrow T(v)=T\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_iv_{i+1}-\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i\Big)v_1+1\times0\Bigg)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_iT(v_{i+1})-\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i\Big)T(v_1)+1\times T(0)$$
But $T(0)$ is unknown. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.

There is a first issue in the question itself. If $V$ is a vector space, it is inappropriate to say that $T: V \mapsto V$ is an affine map and that $v_1,v_2, \dots ,v_{n+1}$ are points of $V$. You have to differentiate the affine space $\mathcal V$ and it’s underlying vector space $V$.

Second, given $n+1$ points in $\mathcal V$, and their images under $\mathcal T$, you can write any point $M \in \mathcal V$ as $M= v_1 +\sum_i \mu_i(v_{i+1}-v_i)$ as $\{v_2-v_1,v_3-v_1,...,v_{n+1}-v_1\}$ spans $V$.

Then $$\mathcal T(M)= \mathcal T(v_1) +\sum_i \mu_i(\mathcal T(v_{i+1})-\mathcal T(v_i))$$ is well defined.

Comment: Regarding your first issue, do we need an affine space to define an affine map? I am defining it from V to V.

Comment: Yes we do need an affine space to define an affine map. However every vector space can be easily endowed with the structure of an affine space.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? What is the problem in defining it from V to V?

Comment: The issue is that points do not even exist in a vector space.

Comment: Why don't they exist in a vector space? Take $Tx=Lx+b$ where $b\in V$ and $L:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation. Then range of $T$ is a subset of $V$, and it is $V$ when $L$ is invertible.

Comment: You can define an affine space on a vector space. But for that you need to define **the origin** of the affine space by choosing a vector.